# Placeholder while retrieving data from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, placeholder

I have a table that contains common subjects text, that requires insertion of some string at run time. For example below:

```
CREATE TABLE certification.cert_email_dtls (
 cert_eid_id numeric(10,0),
 cert_eid_email_body character varying(8000),
);

insert into certification.cert_email_dtls(1,'hello world <blank-value1>);
insert into certification.cert_email_dtls(2,'hello guys <blank-other-value2>);
insert into certification.cert_email_dtls(3,'hello <blank-value3> india <some-other-value4>);
```

and so on. `<some-value>`,`<some-other-value>` etc come at run time.

```
SELECT cert_eid_id ,
       cert_eid_email_body,
INTO   v_id,
       v_email_body_end
FROM certification.cert_email_dtls where cert_eid_id = in_id;
```

My requirement is to insert that some-values that are coming in between and generate the final email body.

Comment: On the one hand, PostgreSQL has `replace()` and `regex_replace()` [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). On the other hand, is there a compelling reason to do this using SQL instead of using application code?

Comment: How many different placeholders are there? Are they unique or can they pop up in multiple rows? Do you retrieve a single row, or many at once? How many placeholders can there be in a single row? Is this supposed to be SQL or PL/pgSQL code in a server side function? And as *always*, your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 0):

[**`format()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) might be the perfect tool for this. Read details in the manual.

If you can save `cert_eid_email_body` in a compatible format, like:

```
CREATE TABLE cert_email_dtls (
   cert_eid_id         serial PRIMARY KEY
 , cert_eid_email_body text
);

INSERT INTO cert_email_dtls (cert_eid_email_body)
VALUES ('hello %1$s india %2$s');
```

The whole operation can be as simple as:

```
SELECT format(cert_eid_email_body, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz') AS cert_eid_email_body
FROM   cert_email_dtls
WHERE  cert_eid_id = 1;
```

Result:

```
cert_eid_email_body
-------------------
hello foo india bar
```

Note that the 3rd parameter `'baz'` is silently ignored, since it is not referenced in the string.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fe736/2)

Aside: Don't use [`numeric(10,0)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) for an ID or primary key. [`integer` or `bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) typically serve you better. Using [`serial PRIMARY KEY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) above as it probably should be.